# "По много(у) раз"

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать/говорить: "по много раз" или "по многу раз", допустима ли вообще вторая форма?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лопатин даёт варианты как нормативные и равноправные .
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EF%EE+%EC%ED%EE%E3%EE

Но, честно говоря, у меня есть некотрые сомнения в отношении именно "разов"... Может, как-то фразу перестроить?